# Bug in CatBoost? CatBoostClassifier doesn't work well with sklearn's CalibratedClassifierCV

Tags: python, classification, calibration, yandex, catboost

catboost version: 0.16

When trying to calibrate the class probability estimates with scikit-learn's `CalibratedClassifierCV`, all I get are 1's for the negative target and 0's for the positive target in a binary classification problem. If I use `CatBoostClassifier` indipendently I get normal looking probabilities. This leads me to believe that this Classifier is not compatible with the calibration technique. Is there a way I can go about fixing this issue?
To reproduce:

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(100, 10)

cat = CatBoostClassifier(verbose=0)
calib = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=cat, method='sigmoid', cv=2)
cat.fit(X, y)
calib.fit(X, y)
print(cat.predict_proba(X))
print(calib.predict_proba(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an open issue with CatBoost. Please check the 
[open issue here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1225).